# How to receive calls in Voximplant?

Tags: voximplant

I built a testing app using the Voximplant platform to make calls, but how do I accept incoming calls?

How do I accept video calls?
Can I receive calls from landline phones as well?
Do I need a special scenario for receiving calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the Voximplant documentation here: https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/calls/scenario#how-to-process-inbound-calls